# Does Ubuntu fix bugs in LTS versions?

Tags: lts, release-management

There is a long-standing [bug 1211110](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/network-manager/+bug/1211110) in `network-manager` that is present in Ubuntu 13.04 up to 16.10 leading to the addition of default gateway to `/etc/resolv.conf` and possible DNS leakage while using a VPN. The bug is [fixed](https://bugs.launchpad.net/network-manager/+bug/1624317/comments/82) in `network-manager`>=1.4.4.

Is it not the Ubuntu policy to fix bugs for the duration of the support period?

Comment: You can raise the flag on [community.ubuntu.com](http://community.ubuntu.com) to attract developers' attention.

Comment: It's more useful to link a bug to the [actual bug report](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/network-manager/+bug/1211110). Since this doesn't seem to be a security bug (the Ubuntu Security Team is not subscribed), the fix won't be backported to older releases.  Since it's a 'high' priority bug, it might be eligible for a [Stable Release Update](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/StableReleaseUpdates), but no users have asked for it. Much of the testing is done by volunteers; if nobody wants to volunteer....

Comment: @user535733 Changed link to point to an actual bug. So, apparently this doesn't qualify as a security bug, huh?

Comment: Not sure what you mean by 'qualify'. There is no checklist. Are you saying that you believe it to be a serious security concern?

Comment: @user535733 Yes, I believe so.

Comment: Read up on how [security bugs](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/SecurityTeam), [Stable Release Updates](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/StableReleaseUpdates), and [Backports](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UbuntuBackports) work. Those will answer most of your questions and show you the way forward to get action.

Answer (score 5):

It is policy backport security bugfixes, although it's not always by shipping the latest package version.  Sometimes, it's just applying the part of the patch that is relevant and bumping the ~ubuntuXXXXX version number not the package version.

That said, a DNS leak might not cross the threshold for serious security bug that merits the man-hours for a backport.